# C# WPF MVVM update label with data calculated from textBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I need to update a label with data calculated from ViewModel. This must be trigged when a textBox is updated because I will use the data from textBox to calcualate the text that must be showed in the label.

My .xaml files is:

```
...
<TextBox x:Name="tbSelectedValue"
    PreviewTextInput="SelectedValue_PreviewTextInput" 
    KeyUp="SelectedValue_KeyUp" 
    Text="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding SelectFileCommand}" />
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>


<Label x:Name="lbSelectedFileName"
    Content="{Binding Path=SelectedName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
...
```

My ViewModel File is:

```
public string SelectedValue
    {
        get { return selectedValue; }
        set { SetProperty(ref selectedValue, value); }
    }
    public string SelectedName
    {
        get { return selectedName; }
        set { selectedName = value; }
    }


   internal string GetSelectName()
    {
        try
        {
            selectedValue = (selectedValue == "" ? "" : GetFileByNumber(Int32.Parse(selectedValue)).name);
            return selectedValue;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "Nenhum arquivo encontrado";
        }
    }
```

The `SelectedValue` works, but `SelectedName` don't work.

I need to call the function `GetSelectName` when the value in textBox is updated (selectedValue). My function `GetSelectName` update the selectedName property and it must be updated in the view. But it's not working.

What I must do?

Comment: `Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`. Why did you choose those flags in particular? What precisely was it about those flags that you thought would be particularly effective in fixing the setter for `SelectedName`?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your solution

Comment: It was a question. I was asking for your reasoning in adding `Mode=TwoWay` to a binding on `Label.Content`.

Comment: No reason. just using all possibilities to try to find the solution

Comment: Did you try renaming your viewmodel? Anyway. are you saying that when the textbox updates `SelectedValue`, you want to call `GetSelectName()`? Or are you saying that when `SelectedValue` updates the TextBox, you want to call `GetSelectName()`? Or both?

Comment: Are you planning to assign the return value of `GetSelectName()` to the `SelectedName` property? `SelectedName` will need to use `SetProperty()` if you want the view to know when its value changes.

Comment: Hi @EdPlunkett, When the textbox change, the SelectedValue are updated (using Prism.Mvvm). I need that after the value in SelectedValue is changed, call the function GetSelectName() that will generate the name and save in SelectedName. When it happen, I need to update the label in the view.

Comment: In function GetSelectName() I'm returning the value SelectedName just to be able to update the view. My request is to remove this direct access from View to ViewModel and use MVVM to update the view

Comment: In answer to the first of those two comments, Karel Tamayo answered your question an hour ago. In answer to the second, I don't understand what you are saying at all. Are you calling `GetSelectName()`? Where are you calling `GetSelectName()`? Tell me where you are calling it. Show me the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @EdPlunkett comments let me put this together and see if it helps.

> Modify SelectedName so it can notify property changes.

```
public string SelectedName
{
    get { return selectedName; }
    set { 
        SetProperty(ref selectedName, value); 
    }
}
```

> Assign the result of the `GetSelectName()` method to `SelectedName`
>   property.

```
public string SelectedValue
{
    get { return selectedValue; }
    set 
    { 
        if (SetProperty(ref selectedValue, value))
        {
            //If property value changes, update the name property as well
            SelectedName = GetSelectedName();
        }
    }
}
```

Does it help?

Comment: It worked. After trying a lot of things and nothing working, I bacame lost in my code. As a beguinner in C#, I was confusing a lot of thing, like, when use "SelectedName" and "selectedName". The solution is simple and clear. Thanks